# How to align a child DIV to center (not middle)?

Tags: html, css, alignment

i spend a day searching for a way to align my child DIV from its parent but all my research show same results.

This is my first time creating a webpage.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnAM.png <== result

https://jsfiddle.net/backspaced/6uy56hw4/ <== Code

```
._header0 {
position: relative ;
white-space: nowrap ;
overflow: hidden ;
text-align: center ;
width: 100% ;
```

Comment: I can't clearly understand your question. Please explain it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are trying to center any div within another div container you can give the inner-div the following CSS:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Then give the outer-div the following CSS:

```
text-align:center;
```

JSFiddle example minus the superfluous markup and styling for ease of understanding.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uy56hw4/5/)